# Find the volume of the ice cream cone bounded by the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ and the cone $z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 - 1}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

When I tried to solve this problem, I can't solve what phi is because I can't draw the trace of the cone in the $yz$-plane.

Usually, if it's $$ z = (y^2)^{1/2}
$$then one could easily draw the absolute value of y but in this case it's different. Do I assume that phi is going from $$ 0\leq \Phi \leq \pi?
$$  Is the cone really a boundary for this problem?

In the end, I used spherical coordinates and my limits of integration are:
$$0\leq \Theta \leq 2\pi,$$
$$ 0\leq \Phi \leq \pi,$$ $$0\leq \rho \leq 2.$$ Is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $z = (x^2 + y^2 - 1)^{1/2}$ isn't a cone, it's (the upper half of) a hyperbolic paraboloid.

Comment: It probably is $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-1$

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that the cone is given by $z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}-1$, as @klirk suggested in the comments above. This intersects the unit sphere along the equator (and also at the south pole). Your ice cream cone is the union of (1) the upper hemisphere, which has volume $\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{4}{3} \pi 1^3 = \frac{2\pi}{3}$, together with (2) the cone [right circular cone] of height one ($-1 \leq z \leq 0$), and base a unit disk, which has volume $\frac{1}{3} B h = \frac{1}{3} \pi 1^2 \cdot 1 = \frac{\pi}{3}$. The total volume is $\pi$.

If you want to use integrals, then it probably makes the most sense to use cylindrical coordinates. Then your integral has limits of integration (bounds) given by
$$
  \int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} \int_{r=0}^1 \int_{z=r-1}^{\sqrt{1-r^2}} .
$$
I hope that is enough help so that you can finish the integral from there.

Alternatively, you could write a double integral for the volume between two graphs (the graph of $z = r-1$ and the graph of $z = \sqrt{1-r^2}$). It's not materially different from the triple integral above.

If you must use spherical coordinates, then it seems to me that you will have to write two separate integrals, one for the hemisphere and one for the cone, and add them together. The hemisphere should be relatively easy ($0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$, $0 \leq \phi \leq \pi/2$, $0 \leq \rho \leq 1$). For the cone, $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ and $\pi/2 \leq \phi \leq \pi$. And $0 \leq \rho \leq a(\phi)$, where $a(\phi)$ is the distance from the origin to the point of intersection of the line $z=r-1$ in the $rz$-plane with the line at angle $\phi$ from "north" (the positive $z$-axis). That latter line is $r/z=\tan(\phi)$. Solving $z=r-1$, $r/z=\tan(\phi)$ gives $z=1/(\tan(\phi)-1)$, $r=\tan(\phi)/(\tan(\phi)-1)$. Hence $a(\phi) = \sec(\phi)/(\tan(\phi)-1)$. The limits of integration are
$$
  \int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} \int_{\phi=\pi/2}^{\pi} \int_{\rho=0}^{\frac{\sec(\phi)}{\tan(\phi)-1}} .
$$